# Multi-walker MCMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, importance-sampling

I just have a brief question regarding Markov Chain Monte Carlo with multiple walkers. I'm currently using this technique to calculate integrals and I'm not 100% on how to combine the statistics of each walker's expectation values. For example, let's say I'm integrating some function $f(x)$ with samples from a probability distribution $p(x)$. If I sample $x$ from $p(x)$ the integral becomes a weighted sum by,

$$ \int f(x) dx = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{f(x_{i})}{p(x_{i})} $$

Now, of course this will reach the exact integral with infinite samples and because $p(x)$ is normalized. In MCMC, using say Metropolis-Hastings we work with the unnormalized probability $\tilde{p}(x)$ and use a self-normalizing estimator.

In MCMC, samples are generated via an accept-reject scheme to form a Markov Chain this chain comes from a single walker which "walks" around the domain collecting samples proportional to $\tilde{p}(x)$ (the unnormalized probability distribution). My question is, if I have multiple walkers collecting samples in their own chains, how exactly can I pool the statistics together to get a global value for the integral? (including an error?).

Would it be as simple as saying taking a mean of all the walkers' mean values? and perhaps error propagating the standard deviations of each chain? (i.e. Euclidean norm) What I've currently implemented to calculate the expected value and variance for each chain is done via the blocking technique which allows calculation of those quantities while including the autocorrelation time of the chain itself (as the variance isn't the same as with i.i.d samples)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're certain that all the walkers have converged to $\tilde{p}(x)$ then taking a mean of all the walkers' mean values and error propagating the standard deviations of each chain sounds sensible. But I would also comment that each walker is drawing samples from the same distribution so the differences in the means and standard deviations should be due to random chance (unlike in a stratified sample, where different sampled sub-populations might inherently have different means/variances).

Comment: You do raise a good point about the walkers converging to $\tilde{p}(x)$, I assume the only way to tell is if they are all giving similar values for the mean and standard deviation, and that the chains have thermalised. But surely, it would be ok to assume that each walker is sampling a sub-population of the total points from all chains? So, perhaps a weight average all of chains could work in giving a global mean and standard deviation of the integral?

Comment: I think just taking a weighted average of all the chains is a good idea. This paper about monitoring convergence may also be of interest: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229099827_General_Methods_for_Monitoring_Convergence_of_Iterative_Simulations

Comment: Thank you for recommending the paper, and for your comments!

Comment: You're welcome!